How to apply code formatting inside markdown-formatted table cells which should present literal backticks?
How do I correct my corrupted table formatting in this answer?
I looks perfectly rendered in the preview section when I am in the editor, but when I submit the edit, it is horribly corrupted.
I have read Markdown Preview Rendering Bug on Large Posts and learned the <pre> tags are the culprit, but <code> (advised by @Machavity) isn't working either.
I want to use inline code styling in table cells AND the code-formatted text will sometimes include backticks.
I don't know how to properly escape the literal backticks to differentiate them from the code-formatting backticks.
I have also attempted to use triple-backtick and triple-tilde wrapping as described in answers on How do I format my code blocks?
What is the solution?
Editor Preview:

Actual Post:


"I have also attempted to use triple-backtick and triple-tilde wrapping as described in answers on How do I format my code blocks?" - did you try wrapping in two backticks?

No, I didn't try double backticks on both sides.  I got the impression that 3 was the magic minimum.

I rather doubt that the third backtick is triggering the bug, but it seems worth a try. Three backticks are used for multi-line code "fences" - and more than three are used if you need that block to include a literal sequence of three or more backticks (at least one more than the longest such sequence). Similarly, for inline code that includes isolated single backticks (which would be confused with the single backtick enclosure otherwise used), two (one more than one) on each side are sufficient.

Quoting: "To use literal backticks within a code span, [use any unique number of multiple backticks][12] as the opening and closing delimiters: both ``literal backtick (`) here`` and, for example, ``````literal backtick (`) here`````` yield literal backtick (`) here. This [works in comments too][13]."

... Except it apparently doesn't (never mind the broken links)... - oh, I didn't read far enough. You can do that sort of thing in comments, but not with backticks at the beginning or end of the code, which requires a different form of escaping. That example is misleading, then...

I eventually tried adding a space after the leading triple backticks and before the trailing triple backticks in each cell.
I was worried that this would give an imprecise rendered output (excess spacing at the start and end of the code-formatted line), but the actual result was visibly trimmed.  Copying the rendered code-formatted text does not include the unwanted space padding. Perfecto.

